# Handling Mouse Scroll event of window datagrid in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Can anybody tell me how to handle mouse scroll event(vertical scroll) in a datagrid? If i scroll the mouse scroller, then datagrid will scrolls. I want to get rowIndex of datagrid's row that is displayed at the top when scroll the grid vertically.

can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **DataGridView Scroll** event

```
 if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
 {
      int i = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MouseWheel and/or PreviewMouseWheel events of the DataGrid
MouseWheel fires when the user ended scrolling, whilst the Preview one fires when the user is about to scroll

Concerning the topmodt drawn index, i cant say anything :/

Hope it helps :p